# how to initialize id in foreach statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, foreach, initialization

I would like to add max id into objects.
I could create ids in array. 
However I need to initialize the first id like 136.

Here is my array

```
  <script>
  const source =  [
  {
   "group": "418",
   "role": "304" 
  },
  {
   "role": "304" 
   "group": "410"
   },
   {
   "role": "304" 
   "group": "420"
   }
];

  var ids = 135   
  source.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.id = i + 1;
  });

console.log(source);
</script>
```

If I run this script, I can get the result as follows.

```
   [ {group: "418", role: "304", id: 1},
     {role: "304", group: "410", id: 2},
     {role: "304", group: "420", id: 3}]
```

I would like to get id from max id + 1
I get maxid from javascript already like 135

How to initialize the id in foreach statement?

This is what I exactly want.

```
   [ {group: "418", role: "304", id: 136},
    {role: "304", group: "410", id: 137},
    {role: "304", group: "420", id: 138}]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You already have `i + 1` which increments by one for every element in the array and you haven't tried `ids + i`?

Comment: just add up the `id` variable to all properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment the id with each loop

```
const source =  [{
  group: "418",
  role: "304" 
},
{
  role: "304",
  group: "410"
},
{
  role: "304",
  group: "420"
}];

var ids = 135   
source.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.id = ids++;
});

console.log(source);
```

Comment: Should be `++ids` because the first element in the example starts with `136`

Answer (score 0):

just add in your offset (your ids variable).

```js
const source =  [
  {
   "group": "418",
   "role": "304" 
  },
  {
   "role": "304",
   "group": "410"
   },
   {
   "role": "304", 
   "group": "420"
   }
];

  var ids = 135   
  source.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.id = i + ids + 1;
  });

console.log(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new array you could use `map` method with a closure.

```js
 const source = [{"group":"418","role":"304"},{"role":"304","group":"410"},{"role":"304","group":"420"}]

const result = (max => source.map(o => ({...o, id: ++max})))(135)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const startId = 135;
  const newSource = source.map((element, i) => {
      return Object.assign({}, element, {
          id: startId + i
      })
      })
  console.log(newSource)
```